# Kotlin coroutines.delay takes too much time on background

Tags: kotlin, background, delay

I have an Android application with kotlin in which I need to do a http request every X seconds (take 10seconds as example), the problem is when after performing a request I want the phone to wait for those 10 seconds. But it happens only when the phone is on background with the screen turned off.

I created a simple example showing that problem, I removed any http request, here I only use the delay and write some logs

On the method onCreate from MainActivity I call this function:

```
    private fun executeCoroutineScope() {
       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (isActive) {
                val sleepTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                delay(10000)
                val sleptTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - sleepTime
                if (sleptTime > 11000) {
                    Log.w("Waking up", "After ${sleptTime / 1000}s")
                } else {
                    Log.v("Waking up", "After ${sleptTime / 1000}s")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

With the phone screen on I see how the sleptTime is always only a few millis above 10seconds, so I write the verbose log. But when the screen is turned of that delay(10000) sometimes takes a few minutes to complete as we can see in the logs [image: here]

The first 2-3 logs were with the screen on, when I turn it off we can see how the sleptTime gets some heavy variations, from 33 secons to even 4 minute and a half.

I tried using `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` and lifecycleScope.launch instead of `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(Dispatchers.IO)` but the results were the same. I also tried with Thread.sleep instead of delay but there was no change in performance either

I also have battery optimization deactivated, so that shouldn't be the problem, any idea how to fix it? (if possible)

Comment: There are no surprises here. Your app execution becomes paused when your app is off screen and you have no foreground service running.

Comment: That's not true, it gives the same problem, the 10s delay took 77, 46, 48, 203, 33, and 49 seconds until I stopped the service. So clearly it's not what you said.

Comment: You’re saying you used a **foreground** service to launch this coroutine and it still had slow timing? That *would* be surprising. I’m not sure what part of my statement you are disputing.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, calling that function inside the `onStartCommand` of the foreground services changes nothing, the delay takes random values, but always way higher than the desired 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

OEM battery-savers can cause this.

I've confirmed on a Samsung SM-T387W, Android 10 - that enabling the OEM battery-saver mode will cause this to happen. Disabling the OEM battery saver stopped the excessive sleeping. I don't believe these are accessible from our apps.

To work around this, I've acquired a WAKE LOCK in the service when I startForeground() and release it when I stopForeground().

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock